# Delete a row if string found on column

Tags: excel, vba

The code takes a table from Workbook (wbI) and paste it as values on a new Workbook (wbO) while keeping the format. This works.

Next I need to search for the string "Blank Interval" on column E and delete the full row of any instance found. This should loop for as long as the data goes, which can change.

I set up a loop based on the total amount of rows after the table is pasted on the new workbook (wb0)

Here is the full code:

```
Sub Output()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook

    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("TempUpload")

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
        wsI.Range("A1:I1").Copy
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wsI.Range("Tupload").Copy
        wsO.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(x1up).Row
    lRow = last_row
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5) = "Blank Interval" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: the first quote on “Blank Interval" is incorrect it should look like the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change on it, but I still get the same error

Comment: Just found the error, was missing a Then. Editing the question

Comment: glad you found it, two problems then...

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I changed the way that the size of the data was calculated.

This is the final code:

```vb
Sub Output()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook

    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("TempUpload")

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
        wsI.Range("A1:I1").Copy
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wsI.Range("Tupload").Copy
        wsO.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    lRow = last_row
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5) = "Blank Interval" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
```